# How is rm command different from the delete button?

Tags: delete, rm

I read from a book where it says, the command `rm` deletes the `inode` and not the file. Which means if I delete with the `rm` command, then it cannot be restored.

I'm very new to Ubuntu environment. Now my doubt is, how does the <kbd>Del</kbd> key works? It is not deleting the `inode` as far as I am concerned, because I can restore it from my `Trash` folder. So am I right to say that <kbd>Del</kbd>  key is doing a `mv` command to `Trash` folder leaving the `inode` unchanged? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your understanding is essentially correct - the <kbd>Del</kbd> key as used in Nautilus (or other file manager) is NOT the same as using `rm`; it "moves" the file to Trash instead so that it can be recovered unless you *Empty Trash* (which is the same as `rm`).

Note that even if you `rm` a file, the actual data is still on the disk after the inode is deleted. If you act immediately before the data is eventually overwritten, you can still recover the data using a tool such as `testdisk/photorec`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you provide a bit more explanation on `the actual data is still on the disk after the inode is deleted`. This line? So when it will be deleted? I mean on what condition the system/kernel deletes the data?

Comment: The system does not delete data; at some point it will just re-use that space as it is seen as 'unused' to the system @Ant's  But techically the data is still there; it is just that the reference (inode) to that file is deleted.

Comment: I'm not sure about your exact distro, but in kubuntu, shift+del is the same as rm.

Answer (score 1):

Delete just transfers the files / folders (things you have deleted) to the trash, while "rm" command permanently removes that thing/s from your hard disk.

**NOTE :** You can still recover permanently deleted files. To "not" do that you will have to shred the file so that it cannot be recovered.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to permanently delete the Files... You would have to use  'srm'  .. This would delete and then overwrite the sectors of the disc, which held the file.