# Difference between move to trash and rm on the terminal?

Tags: command-line, delete, trash, watchdog

I am using `watchdog`, a python package to monitor changes in the file system. The code works fine on Mac but it seems that the delete event is not monitored correctly in ubuntu. If I do a `rm` instead of move the file to trash, `watchdog` is able to detect the change. I am wondering whether there is a difference between moving to trash and `rm` command on the terminal in ubuntu that might lead to this behavior. 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In layman's terms,

`rm` [unlinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unlink_(Unix)) the file.

"moving to trash" is something equivalent to `mv file ~/.local/share/Trash` in terminal, which means the file was moved from one directory to another directory.

P.S.: [This question](https://askubuntu.com/q/174906/182274) came up as the first result when I did a Google search for "[ubuntu rm trash difference](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+rm+trash+difference)". I hope you can do some research next time before you ask.

Comment: This is the first result when I did a Google search for "move to trash vs rm".